# Is there an elliptic curve mod n with exactly one point?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have tried many elliptic curves $y^2 = x^3 + ax +b$ with no success. I know that for prime modules there exists a minimum number of points the elliptic curve has to have, and I couldn't satisfy this for the smallest primes. So I decided to try luck with modules with few quadratic residues such as 8. But again, no luck.

Comment: Do you know [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma)?

Comment: There is an elliptic curve modulo $2$ with just one point defined over the integers modulo $2$. Being of characteristic two, one cannot write its equation as $y^2=x^3+ax+b$.

Comment: If $p | n, p^2 \nmid n$ then let $e_p \equiv 1 \bmod p, e_p \equiv 0 \bmod \frac{n}{p}$, the map $(x,y) \mapsto (e_p x,e_p y)$ is an embedding $E/(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) \to E/(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, the former being well-understood in term of the characteristic polynomial of the Frobenius.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why not? Is there a way to write it down then?

Comment: @Servaes No, reading it now.

Comment: Do you want to require $n>1$?

Comment: I couldn't find the elliptic curve modulo 2 even when I used the general form of equation $y^2+a_1xy + a_5y  = x^3 +a_2x^2 + a_3x + a_4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: $y^2 + y = x^3 + x +1 \pmod{2}$. The only element here is the point in infinity: the neutral element.

Answer (score 2):

You can also construct an answer mod 3 (which is in short weierstrass form) as follows:

For all $x \in \mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$ we know by Fermat's little theorem that $x^3 = x$, therefore the polynomial $x^3 - x + 2$ always takes the value $2$ on elements of $\mathbf Z/3 \mathbf Z$, as 2 is not  a square in this ring the curve

$$y^2= x^3 - x + 2$$

has no non-infinite points.